How find a limit analytically by definiton?
According to the definition of the, for example, finite limit as x tends to infinity, for any real $\epsilon$, greater than zero, there should $\delta$, so for any absolute value $x$ from the domain greater than $\delta$, $f(x) $ of such $x$ should be in $\epsilon$ neighourgood of the finite limit value $A$:
$$\forall \epsilon > 0 \space \exists\delta(\epsilon)>0\space x \in X:|x|>\delta \space => |f(x) - A|<\epsilon$$
In case of $\frac{1}{x}$ the greater $\epsilon$ we consider, the smallest $\delta$ we get.
But it seems like we should infinitevely enumerate $\epsilon$ to check if there is needed $\delta$.
I do not understand how such great definition helps to find a limit analytically, generalized.
When we solve limits we use stuff like L`Hopitale rule, we generally just solve them as equations, but I do not understand where that great (no irony) definition is used? Can it be used to actually find a limit analytically, or it can be used only to check some value to be or not to be a limit of given function?
I mean, one have a function, and want to find its limit as x tends to infinity. Can they do that only using limit definition, i.e. via epsilon, delta and not by enumarating specific candidates for limit, or epsilon, but comletely analytically, in generalized form.
For example in case of $ax^2 +bx +c = 0$ we do not need to consider any specific $x$ to find them, we just use generalized formulas. Definition of the limit is not such?

Do you know the formal definition of limit from the question?

@zkutch, yes I added it to the post

Are you confused about limits in general, or just limits as $x \to \infty$? i.e. do you get why the definition works for $x$ going to a finite number?

I don't quite understand your post, but regarding your sentence, "But it seems like we should infinitevely enumerate $\varepsilon$ to check if there is needed $\delta$" – this is not correct. Usually, in an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, we show that for an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ (dependent on $\varepsilon$) such that.... We don't need to consider all possible values of $\varepsilon>0$ simultaneously – just like we don't need to consider all values of $t\in\mathbb R$ simultaneously when proving that for all $t\in\mathbb R$, the identity $(t+1)^2=t^2+2t+1$ holds.

Instead, we let $t$ be an arbitrary real, conclude that $(t+1)^2=t^2+2t+1$, and then deduce that, since $t$ was arbitary, it must be the case that $(t+1)^2=t^2+2t+1$ for all $t\in\mathbb R$.

@ZoeAllen, maybe not even limit in generall themself, but the idea of the criteria. You say, that 0 is limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x}$, because I can't provide You such epsilon, so there will not be delta, that satifsfies the condifion. Joe, also - I probably a bit missed, that for wrong $A$

@Joe, what is the same approach for finding (proving) the limit?

@sahgasdvsadgv: In your example, the proof would go something like this: "let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary. We claim that there is a $\delta$ such that, for all $x$, if $x>\delta$, then $|1/x|<\varepsilon$. Indeed, if $x>1/\varepsilon$, then $0<1/x<\varepsilon$, so $|1/x|<\varepsilon$. Thus, we can take $\delta=1/\varepsilon$."

@ZoeAllen and Joe, I probably just missed, considering wrong $A$ is a limit, one can find $\epsilon$, so there will be $\delta$ such that not for all $x$ greater than $\delta$ the condition $|f(x)-A|<\epsilon$ satifsfies, i.e. there x's,  for which it is not satisfied. But I rather do not understand how we can check it not by enumarating?

@sahgasdvsadgv: To show that the limit does not equal $A$, you need to show that there is an $\varepsilon>0$, such that for all $\delta$, there is an $x$ such that $x>\delta$ and $|1/x - A|\ge\varepsilon$. It seems that perhaps your confusion is to do with negating logical statements. You might want to read a question I asked about this three years ago.

(Sorry, my previous comment had a mistake in it. I've edited it out.) For example, if $A=1$, then you could take $\varepsilon=1/2$. It might be worth trying this out as an exercise.

@Joe, yeah, probably the thing that is confusing, is that in books, delta is show as some abstract function of epsilon. I think this the key - to prove, one just needs to find that $\delta(\epsilon)$

@Joe I rewrite my post to generalize it.

@Joe, hmm, but You just provided kind of first level of abstractization. First, we literally enumarating values, next we find analytical equation to find $A$ - $\delta(\epsilon)$, but for particular case - for $1/x$. Maybe we can make some exact dependece of delta over epsilon for any function? If it is please do not provide it, I want to do it on my own, just tell, please if it is or not

@sahgasdvsadgv No, $\delta(\epsilon)$ can't be chosen independently of the function: Suppose that it could be and consider $\epsilon=1$. Moreover, define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=2$ for $x<\delta(1)+1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq\delta(1)+1$. Obviously, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, so we should have $f(x)=|f(x)-0|<\epsilon=1$ for $x>\delta(1)$. However, this is not true for $x=\delta(1)+0.5$. Thus, $\delta(\epsilon)$ does depend on the function you consider.

@math-jl, I think, if limit $A$ exists at some finite limit point $x_0$, then $\delta(\epsilon)=f^{-1}(\epsilon+A)-x_0$. Is not it?

@sahgasdvsadgv Note that this choice again depends on $f$. As i proved above, it has to, I just want to make sure that this is clear. Moreover, this choice doesn't work for several reasons: 1. $f$ doesn't even have to attain the value $\epsilon+A$. 2. Even if it does, there doesn't have to be a unique preimage of $\epsilon+A$. 3. By just choosing any of the preimages, you might obtain an invalid $\delta$: Consider $f=sin,x_0=0,A=0,\epsilon=0.5$. Then $f(\frac{13}{6}\pi)=0.5=\epsilon+A$ and $|\frac{\pi}{2}-x_0|<\delta(\epsilon)=\frac{13}{6}$, but $|f(\frac{\pi}{2})-A|=1>0.5=\epsilon$.
